# Creating a unittest for a caught exception that I cannot seem to be able to force

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube

I have this method here and it works fine but I have trouble creating a unit test for the exception part of the method as I can not force the UnsupportedEncodingException. The encoder is a constant?!

Just to be clear the 'parse()' method used does some manipulation of a parameter in the string before encoding it again.

```
public String encode(final String term) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(parse(URLDecoder.decode(term, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log.error("The provided query does not seem to be correctly formatted", e);
        return "";
    }
}
```

I even tried to create a test by manipulating the constant in the class to something else by using code like below to manipulate this constant to something else, but it does not seem to work. I can not seem to force this error.

```
public static void injectStaticFinal(final Field declaredField, final Object newValue) throws Exception {
    declaredField.setAccessible(true);
    final Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(declaredField, declaredField.getModifiers() & ~FINAL);
    declaredField.set(null, newValue);
}
```

by writing this test case

```
@Test
public void unsupportedEncodingException() throws Exception {
    final SearchTerm searchTerm = new SearchTerm();
    TestUtil.injectStaticFinal(searchTerm, "UTF_8", "just wrong encoder");
    assertThat(searchTerm.encode("hallo"), is(""));
}
```

This test fails because the exception is never thrown...

So SonarQube tells me that it is not covered in test but in this case I have no idea how to??? I'm happy with the code but not happy with the sonar message...

Comment: There's no point in testing that exception. It can never happen, since any JVM MUST support UTF8. But you should use StandardCharSets.UTF8 rather than your own constant, and throw an IllegalStateException from the catch block rather than returning an incorrect result. Just ignore the Sonar warning. The tool is supposed to help you, not enslave you.

Comment: I agree completely with the first and thanks for the tip. I also don't want any sonar issues, so it became an test to get it done and then it became a frustration :-). I don't agree with the second part as the empty string is precisely what I want in this case.

Comment: and just to be overly precise : you may see the result in sonarqube but this is your coverage tool (JaCoCo ?) telling you the branch is not covered. And I second all the answers on that post : no need to test this, accept this as the % of coverage it is fine to not have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting by reflection the `UTF_8` constant may make Sonar happy but it doesn't cover the actual code as it changes the **real implementation**.
Here what you want to test is that an `UnsupportedEncodingException` is thrown as the  character encoding `UTF-8` is not supported.
Which doesn't make really sense as UTF-8 is generally supported by most of operating systems.

You have two ways.

1) The most natural one : accept that the branch be not covered by an unit test

2) More convoluted way and I don't advise it but much better as using reflection and writing a tricky test : overload the method with `encoding`, an additional parameter  and extract your actual code in.
Your actual method (without the parameter) could so invoke the overloaded one with `UTF-8` as param.
And you would have so a way to test the exception scenario by providing an invalid charset.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same and accepting the branch is not covered :-) I don't like to change my code for this reason as it does not make it simpler and even makes it more breakable...

Comment: @Ivonet Implementation classes matter but test classes too. I will not write a tricky/not maintainable test to keep a good implementation I will that both be acceptable.  That's why  I agree that the first option is better.

Comment: Yup agree completely... going for the first :-)